# PHP Login and Cookies work on front page ONLY

Tags: php, cookies, login-script

i am just learn php a week ago. but now i have a problem. my php login and session script, work in front page ONLY. when i tested with clear cookies, and type in browser to spesific page on my site (example: www.mysite.com/page34.html) THE LOGIN FORM IS NOT SHOW.

Why user that not login yet can access my specific page of my site?

ceklogin.php

```
    <?php
    include "koneksi.php";

    /* Variable declarationl */
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    /* check data with my sql db in server */ 
    $user  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' AND  password='$password'");
    $match = mysql_num_rows($user);

    if ($match==1){
        echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.mysite.com/page1.html'</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<h1>Username and Password not match</h1>";    
    }
    ?>
```

index.php

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_COOKIE['AboutVisit']))
 echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.mypage.com/page1.html'</script>"
?>
<?php 
 $hour = 10800 + time(); 
 //this adds 1 hour to the current time 
 setcookie(AboutVisit, date("F jS - g:i a"), $hour);
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Area</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>    
    <form action="ceklogin.php" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><h1>Form Login </h1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Username</td><td> : <input type="text" name="username"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Password</td><td> : <input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" align="right">
    <input type="submit" value="Login"> <input type="reset" value="Batal"></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

koneksi.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("mysql server","my username","password") or die("Koneksi failed");
mysql_select_db("u674105401_01") or die("Database not exist");
//i am hiding my sql server, username, and password in this post
?>
```

Why user that not login yet can accees my specific page of my site?

Which one is wrong?

Comment: `www.mysite.com/page34.html` PHP does not run on `.html` files on default.

Comment: your code suggest that you haven't use session.

Comment: Also, remember to `start_session()` on each script.

Comment: Dave, PHP doesnot run in hml files? ok i this s a learning

Comment: Rajeev, no i am just using cookie. i am not interest in session. sorry wrong title. i mean COOKIES not session

Comment: You probably still have the cookie set in your browser from debugging. When working with sessions / cookies, always remember to clear your browser cookies when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Remove `?><?php`

2 - `setcookie('AboutVisit', xxx);`

Comment: 1. i already try to remove this. but not work. then i use { } thats work in front page ONLY. user still can acces my spesific site. 2 do you mean 'date("F jS - g:i a")' mustbe removed

Comment: 2 . You don't use quotes around AboutVisit

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using window.location you can use the php [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function

Example: `header('Location: http://www.mypage.com/page1.html');`

Comment: whats the difference? it's just make a frontpage, isn it? if i change it, my trully problem still remain: user not login yet, can acces my specifik page

Comment: This will not solve the problem but it's unnecessary to use javascript for that. This is just a tip